# bash: How to know the source of generated signals when trapped?

Tags: bash, signals

I wish to know, when a signal is caught at my signal handler, who really generated the signal. Is it user generated, or system generated, or by the OOM (Out-Of-Memory Management).
The problem is, i am running database alterations using percona toolkit, and it is getting stopped everytime using SIGHUP after some 2-3 hours.

I installed a signal handler, to catch it, but wish to knwo, where it came from.
An example program is below:

```
trapCount=0

trapFunc()
{
 trapCount=`expr $trapCount + 1`
 echo "Sighup received...$trapCount" # But how to know who generated it
}

trap 'trapFunc' HUP

while [ 1 ]
do
 echo "First Line"
 sleep 1
 echo "Second Line"
 sleep 1
 echo "Third Line"
 sleep 1
 echo "Fourth Line"
 sleep 1
 echo "Sixth Line"
 sleep 1
 echo "Seventh Line"
 sleep 1
 echo "Eighth Line"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't; signals are delivered by the operating system, on behalf of an anonymous signaler.

Comment: So, there is absolutely no way for a debug trace? That's really unfortunate.

Comment: At least in this case, though, `SIGHUP` means the controlling terminal was closed (or at least, someone wants your code to *think* the controlling terminal was closed).

Comment: The script was run using a `nohup`, but it was strange, that it was still getting closed by `sighup`. I was the sole user running that machine, and mysql was the only program running, in addition to my script.